# Linux: Unix domain datagram sockets don't follow specification of connect/recv, do they?

Tags: sockets, unix, ipc, datagram, unix-socket

The manual of `connect` says:

> If the socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only address from which datagrams are received.

The following C program seems to reveal an error in the Linux implementation of `connect`/`recv` on UNIX domain sockets, as it receives a message from an address (`@"PWE0"`) other than the one it has connected to (`@"STAR"`), and terminates. In contrast to that, the behaviour I expect is that the program doesn't terminate, because it faithfully waits for a message from the address it has connected to, which never arrives. (I deliberately didn't clutter the example with return value checks and print statements, since it can easily be examined with `strace`; in real life, the calls would be made by different processes.)

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

char header[] = "PLD ";

int main()
{
#define addrlen sizeof(unsigned short) + sizeof (char [1+4]) + sizeof(int)
    int fd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
       bind(fd, &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0PLD " }, addrlen);
    int gd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
       bind(gd, &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0STAR" }, addrlen);
    int hd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
       bind(hd, &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0PWE0" }, addrlen);
    sendto(hd, "PWE0\0\0\0\n\1h\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1", 18, 0,
                &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0PLD " }, addrlen);
    connect(fd, &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0STAR" }, addrlen);
    char buf[32];
    return recv(fd, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
}
```

So, is Linux [as well as HP-UX (with file system pathnames)] violating the specification, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** I noticed my first answer was wrong. So I edited a lot of the text.

**EDIT2** Fixed addrlen taking into account that abstract address space is being used. The behaviour of the code remained the same.

Your definition of the `addrlen` is a bit baffling.

1. You seem to only reserve 4+1 bytes for the address path. I figure, that "\0|P|L|D| |\0" is 6 bytes.
2. Where does the `sizeof(int)` come from? I could not figure out what you meant by it.

However, I think the reason the sendto goes through, is the order of the `sendto()` and `connect()`. If you move the connect before the sendto, you get the behaviour you expected. Unix sockets buffer the datagrams. The sent datagram goes through before the connect "starts filtering". In the case where the connect and sendto are swapped, you can see the datagram being filtered when its received by the OS (from the sender). Seems there is no more filtering, when the user space application calls recv.

```
Here is an strace output (last lines only) of the modified program.
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)          = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@"PLD "}, 8) = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)          = 4
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@"STAR"}, 8) = 0
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)          = 5
bind(5, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@"PWE0"}, 8) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@"STAR"}, 8) = 0
sendto(5, "PWE0\0\0\0\n\1h\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1", 18, 0, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@"PLD "}, 8) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
recvfrom(3, ^C <unfinished ...>
```

I changed the compact way of defining the addresses inside the function calls. Here is my modified code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
int main()
{
    const char hdr [] = "\0PLD ";
    socklen_t addrlen =  sizeof(sa_family_t) + sizeof(hdr);

    int fd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bind(fd, &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0PLD " }, addrlen);
    int gd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bind(gd, &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0STAR" }, addrlen);
    int hd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    bind(hd, &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0PWE0" }, addrlen);

    connect(fd, &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0STAR" }, addrlen);
    sendto(hd, "PWE0\0\0\0\n\1h\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1", 18, 0,
           &(struct sockaddr){ AF_UNIX, "\0PLD " }, addrlen);

    char buf[32];
    return recv(fd, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
}
```

I do admit it is a bit baffling. There must be some undefined behaviour relating to the `addrlen` parameter of `bind()`, since if I only change your original codes addrlen to sizeof(struct sockaddr_un), I get a different behaviour, where the connect() is refused and the recv blocks (maybe my modified code has a bug I did not see).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to beg your pardon for not further stripping down the example; the extra `sizeof(int)` bytes come from the original application, where they were intended to distinguish identical names in multiple program instances (like `"\0STAR\0\0\0\0"`, `"\0STAR\0\0\0\1"` or similar). However, the address paths in my example have 14 Bytes reserved for them, since they are the `char sa_data[14];` of `struct sockaddr`.

Comment: You are right in your last paragraph: You indeed create undefined behaviour if you just change addrlen to `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`, which is 110, since this causes 94 Bytes beyond the end of the provided `struct sockaddr` to be examined.

Comment: Your observation regarding the order of sendto() and connect() is quite interesting, and your interpretation plausible (will upvote the answer as soon as I get reputation 15). Still, I suspect the Linux implementation of being faulty, since the documentation of `connect` states no constraints regarding the chronological order with respect to `sendto`, and in a multi process environment, requiring a certain sequence would be well-nigh silly, in my opinion.

Comment: Re your 3rd comment. Have you observed different behaviour on some other platform? Is this a feature in code you are porting? I agree to your interpretation of `connect()`, but there is also another point of view. The unix domain sockets on Linux are defined to be reliable, even when using datagrams. Accepting a datagram from a sending process and then silently discarding it, when the receiver calls `connect()` is not very reliable transport. It gives neither party the possibility to detect the error. In the current behaviour both the client and sender can detect the unwanted address.

Comment: Re your 2nd comment. I must point out that it is not strictly correct to provide and `struct sockaddr` to a `bind()` on a PF_UNIX socket. The parameter is supposed to refer to a `struct sockaddr_un ` cast to a `struct sockaddr`. The kernel side implementation is surely responsible for interpreting the provided data structure correctly, as is the user space for providing one. Though the abstract name space is a peculiar (and non-portable) special case, since '\0' is a valid character and I see now how my structures were interpreted wrong.

Comment: I now observed same behaviour on HP-UX (with file system pathnames). Maybe this is the usual implementation, and just the manual is wrong or imperfect. I was developing a communication library... Re your thoughts about `connect`: I agree that discarding a datagram would be unacceptable. What I had in mind was that `recv` would read the datagram from the connected process/address, leaving other datagrams untouched and ready for being received later, similar to what `msgrcv` with the message type argument does.